# Spring Cloud Stream - failed to deserialize - failed to resolve class name. Class not found

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Application A writes to a Kafka Topic below User object (json):

```
public class UserEvent {
   private UUID id; 
   private Object payload; // contains User fields name etc.
}
```

Application B is trying to consume this User object (User.java resides in application B project) with below application.yml (multiple binders):

```
    binders:
    azureEventHub:
        type: kafka
        environment:
            spring:
                kafka:
                    bootstrap-servers: servicebus.windows.net:9093
                    consumer:
                        key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                        value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                        properties:
                            spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                            spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
                            spring.json.trusted.packages: com.*
                            spring.json.value.default.type: com.applicationb.User
```

Below is how my Spring Cloud Stream Processor class looks:

```
  @Bean 
  public Function<Message<User>, String> userProcessor()  
  {..  }
```

But instead of converting the Message payload to "User" class it keeps throwing the error with the
Parent class "UserEvent" not found.

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: 
Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: 
failed to deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: 
failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.abcd.UserEvent]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abcd.UserEvent
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You may want to try it against a local Kafka cluster and see if the problem still persists. In that case, please feel free to share a small reproducible sample app for us to triage further.

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer will use type information in the headers before falling back to the default (`User`).

Also set `spring.json.use.type.headers` to `false`.